# waitForQueueAsync throws Sys.ArgumentNullException Value cannot be null. Parameter name: clientObject

Tags: project-server, client-object-model

I'm trying to update a resource (using JSOM) by adding a calendar exception, but I'm getting a Sys.ArgumentNullException when running the request on the server

Here's a piece of my code:

```
// Initialize the current client context.
projContext = PS.ProjectContext.get_current();

// Get the collection of enterprise resources.
resources = projContext.get_enterpriseResources();

// Register the request for information that you want to run on the server.
projContext.load(resources, "Include(Id, Name, ResourceCalendarExceptions, IsGeneric)");

// Run the request on the server.
projContext.executeQueryAsync(UpdateResources, QueryFailed);

function UpdateResources(response)
{
    // Initialize a CalendarExceptionCreationInformation object and specify properties.
    var creationInfo = new PS.CalendarExceptionCreationInformation();
    creationInfo.set_name("Vacations");

    // Specify properties.
    creationInfo.set_start("2013-09-20 00:00:00.000");
    creationInfo.set_start("2013-09-21 00:00:00.000");

    var resourceId = "XXX";
    var resource = resources.getById(resourceId);

    // Add the calendar exception to the collection.
    resource.get_resourceCalendarExceptions().add(creationInfo);

    // Submit the request to update the collection on the server
    var updateJob = resources.update();
    projContext.waitForQueueAsync(updateJob, 10, IterateThroughResources);
}
```

Comment: can that be simply because you have `creationInfo.set_start` twice and none of `creationInfo.set_end`? :)

Comment: Hi Andrey! You're right! However, I replaced the second `creationInfo.set_start`with `creationInfo.set_finish` (I think there's no set_end), and it still shows the same error

Comment: I even removed the code that adds the new calendar exception and just tried to update the collection `var updateJob = resources.update(); projContext.waitForQueueAsync(updateJob, 10, IterateThroughResources);`, and I get the same error as before. Seems to be something missing in the collection, or in a specific Enterprise Resource, but I can't figure out what that might be.

Comment: Hi Andrey. I was debugging my code and I see that the update method returns undefined. In other words, after this line is called `var updateJob = resources.update();`, the variable updateJob is undefined. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

I used `executeQueryAsync` instead of `waitForQueueAsync` and also enabled administrative permissions.

Hope it helps!